# I don't know how to get the right output

Tags: console

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class NumberWord {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        String word = x.nextLine();

        int number = x.nextInt();
        System.out.println(number + ","+" " + word);
    }
}
```

I want to write the program that reads in from the console a string and an integer and then outputs the integer followed a comma, a space, and then the string. For example, if the input is `Wow` and `10` then your output should be `10, Wow`.

Comment: Code looks good. no?

Comment: But I got an error message the is "Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException"

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: did you get the issue?

Answer (score 0):

OK.. so this is my code, copied from yours..

```
public class NumberWord {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
    String word = x.nextLine();

    int number = x.nextInt();
    System.out.println(number + "," + " " + word);
  }
}
```

And them here is the output. Isnt this as expected?

[image]

**IMP:** Because you are using nextLine, make sure that you are pressing `Enter` after intering `Wow` and then after `10` as well.

BTW, Are you entering `10` first and then `wow` like below?
[image]